# GRUB booting only Ubuntu but not Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have Windows 8 installed in C drive (by default from Lenovo) & Ubuntu separately installed in another partition.

When I start my computer it leads straight to the GRUB menu. There I can see options to load Ubuntu and Windows 8.

When I select Ubuntu it works fine, but when I select Windows 8 option, then it leads straight back to the GRUB menu.

Hence I am unable to boot into Windows 8 via the GRUB menu (the only way I can boot into Windows 8 is by using the one touch recovery button).

Answer (score 0):

Boot Ubuntu. Try opening a terminal by holding down CTRL and ALT and tapping T and then issue the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should find your windows 8 installation again. If this doesn't work it's possible you've overwritten your Windows 8 boot sector which you would need to repair with windows 8 media and then reinstall grub (making sure you don't overwrite the windows boot sector again) so you can boot ubuntu.

Comment: are u suggesting to do this when  grub loader appears during startup or when i have already booted inside ubuntu?

Comment: @user274700 booted inside ubuntu

Comment: it says "grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root"

Comment: @user274700 edited answer